# Selenium webdriver: Unknown error: cannot determine loading status

Tags: eclipse, selenium-webdriver, exception, salesforce-lightning

I am using chrome browser : 88.0.4324.146
Chrome driver : 88.0.4324.96

I am working on Selenium webdriver using eclipse Java. Automating salesforce lightning application.
But after my code reaching a particular point the below error  is shown
Unknown error: Cannot determine loading status

Comment: You need to post minimal, reproducible code. Posting the entire error message output to the console might be nice to show as well.